# Best and/or fastest way to create lists in python

Tags: python, list

In python, as far as I know, there are at least 3 to 4 ways to create and initialize lists of a given size:

**Simple loop with `append`:**

```
my_list = []
for i in range(50):
    my_list.append(0)
```

**Simple loop with `+=`:**

```
my_list = []
for i in range(50):
    my_list += [0]
```

**List comprehension:**

```
my_list = [0 for i in range(50)]
```

**List and integer multiplication:**

```
my_list = [0] * 50
```

In these examples I don't think there would be any performance difference given that the lists have only 50 elements, but what if I need a list of a million elements? Would the use of `xrange` make any improvement? Which is the preferred/fastest way to create and initialize lists in python?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Let's run some time tests* with [`timeit.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>
>>> # Test 1
>>> test = """
... my_list = []
... for i in xrange(50):
...     my_list.append(0)
... """
>>> timeit(test)
22.384258893239178
>>>
>>> # Test 2
>>> test = """
... my_list = []
... for i in xrange(50):
...     my_list += [0]
... """
>>> timeit(test)
34.494779364416445
>>>
>>> # Test 3
>>> test = "my_list = [0 for i in xrange(50)]"
>>> timeit(test)
9.490926919482774
>>>
>>> # Test 4
>>> test = "my_list = [0] * 50"
>>> timeit(test)
1.5340533503559755
>>>
```

As you can see above, the last method is the fastest by far.

---

However, it should *only* be used with immutable items (such as integers).  This is because it will create a list with references to the same item.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> lst = [[]] * 3
>>> lst
[[], [], []]
>>> # The ids of the items in `lst` are the same
>>> id(lst[0])
28734408
>>> id(lst[1])
28734408
>>> id(lst[2])
28734408
>>>
```

This behavior is very often undesirable and can lead to bugs in the code.

If you have mutable items (such as lists), then you should use the still very fast list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [[] for _ in xrange(3)]
>>> lst
[[], [], []]
>>> # The ids of the items in `lst` are different
>>> id(lst[0])
28796688
>>> id(lst[1])
28796648
>>> id(lst[2])
28736168
>>>
```

---

*Note: In all of the tests, I replaced `range` with `xrange`.  Since the latter returns an iterator, it should always be faster than the former.

Comment: +1 I have deleted my answer, please include the reason why we should use it with only immutable items.

Comment: Note that xrange is not available in `python 3.x`, though I assume that `xrange` has been replaced with `range` in `python 3.x`.

Comment: Using `range()` in 3.3.3 I get the following results (using `%timeit` magic in IPython) in μs/loop: append - 44.1, loop - 77.1, comprehension - 20.5, multiplication - 2.26.

Comment: @PascalvKooten `range` in Python 3 works like `xrange` in Python 2. They both return an iterator instead of creating a list like Python 2’s `range` does.

Comment: Ok great answer, but do you know why? Do you by any chance know any implementation details about the multiplication method that makes it so fast?

Comment: @ecampver - The multiplication method doesn't need to create numerous unique items (which takes time).  Instead, it creates one item and then makes the rest of the items references to that item.

Answer (score 38):

If you want to see the dependency with the length of the list `n`:

### Pure python

[image]

I tested for list length up to n=10000 and the behavior remains the same. So the integer multiplication method is the fastest with difference.

### Numpy

For lists with more than ~300 elements you should consider [numpy](http://www.numpy.org).

[image]

Benchmark code:

```
import time

def timeit(f):

    def timed(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.clock()
        for _ in range(100):
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.clock()
        return end - start
    return timed

@timeit
def append_loop(n):
    """Simple loop with append"""
    my_list = []
    for i in xrange(n):
        my_list.append(0)

@timeit
def add_loop(n):
    """Simple loop with +="""
    my_list = []
    for i in xrange(n):
        my_list += [0]

@timeit   
def list_comprehension(n):        
    """List comprehension"""
    my_list = [0 for i in xrange(n)]

@timeit
def integer_multiplication(n):
    """List and integer multiplication"""
    my_list = [0] * n


import numpy as np

@timeit
def numpy_array(n):
    my_list = np.zeros(n)
    

import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([(integer_multiplication(n), numpy_array(n)) for n in range(1000)], 
                  columns=['Integer multiplication', 'Numpy array'])
df.plot()
```

Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/elyase/8161939).

Comment: What is causing the huge sudden spike at ~500 for both methods?

Comment: I was wondering the same. It seems to be random fluctuations with no particular reason, maybe the PC was busy doing something else at that particular moment. If I repeat the benchmark the peaks go away or appear at different value of the list length.

Comment: It seems to be near 512. Perhaps some memory alignment issue?

Comment: Maybe garbage collector?

Comment: On your first diagram, the list and integer multiplication seems to be constant while it is not if we look on the [0 - 20] X range on the second diagram. Is there any explanation to that ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva good catch! I posted the benchmarking code too. Do you see any mistake I missed there?

Answer (score 2):

There is one more method which, while sounding weird, is handy in right curcumstances. If you need to produce the same list many times (initializing matrix for [roguelike pathfinding and related stuff](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=The_Incredible_Power_of_Dijkstra_Maps) in my case), you can store a copy of the list in the tuple, then turn it to list when you need it. It is noticeably quicker than generating list *via* comprehensions and, unlike list multiplication, works with nested data structures.

```
#  In class definition
def __init__(self):
    self.l = [[1000 for x in range(1000)] for y in range(1000)]
    self.t = tuple(self.l)

def some_method(self):
    self.l = list(self.t)
    self._do_fancy_computation()
    #  self.l is changed by this method

#  Later in code:
for a in range(10):
    obj.some_method()
```

Voila, on every iteration you have a fresh copy of the same list in no time!

## Disclaimer:

I do not have a slightest idea why is this so quick or whether it works anywhere outside CPython 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list incrementing, i.e. adding 1 every time, use the `range` function. In `range` the start argument is included and the end argument is excluded as shown below:

```
list(range(10,20))
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

If you want to create a list by adding 2 to previous elements use this:

```
list(range(10,20,2))
[10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Here the third argument is the step size to be taken. Now you can give any start element, end element and step size and create many lists fast and easy.

Thank you..!

Happy Learning.. :)