# Optimizing execution time for appending data (Python)

Tags: python, list, loops, google-bigquery

Since we are able to get hundred of thousands of data from bigQuery, the execution time for the code given below will be too long. Is there a better way to reduce the runtime (optimize the code)?

```
dataList = []
for row in dataRow:
    data = dict(row)

    if data['LedgerKey']:
         dataList.append(data)
```

Comment: You can try list comprehension and see if you gain some time. Use `dataList = [row for row in dataRow]`. List comprehensions are faster than the append as exemplified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20816852/4932316)

Comment: @Bazingaa I edit the code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Cython](https://cython.org/), which can compile the code and call C-Extensions directly