# how to create a dynamic list to read and update for each script run

Tags: python-3.x

i have a script which runs some checks for all DB's.Now i want to have a list such that this list contains all the DB's already checked.So the next time the script runs it will read this list  and if the DB is not in that list only then the checks happen.
What is the best way to implement this? If i initialize a empty list(DB_checked) and append each DB name while the checks are run,the issue would be that each time the script starts the list would again be empty.
Please suggest.Thanks.

At the end of the script will call the below function to write to disk:

```
    def writeDBList(db_checked):
        with open(Path(__file__).parent / "db_names.txt", "w") as fp:
            for s in job_names:
                fp.write(str(s) +"\n")
        return
```

When the script starts will call the below to read the file from disk:

```
    def readDBList():
        with open(Path(__file__).parent / "db_names.txt", "r") as fp:
           for line in fp:
                db_list.append(line.strip())
        return
```

But how to convert the file contents to a list so that i can easily check with below:

```
    checked_list = readDBList()
    if db not in checked_list:
        ....
        ....
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best and/or fastest way to create lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816600/best-and-or-fastest-way-to-create-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write this list to the disk after the script finishes the checks, and read it again in the beginning of the script in the next script run.

```
# Read DB CheckList
DB_List = readDBList()

# Your normal script functionality for only DBs not in the list

# Store DB CheckList
writeDBList(DB_List)
```

Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) in case you are not familiar with I/O file handling in python.

Now, regarding your second question about how to read the list. I would suggest using **pickle**, which allows you to read/write python structures without worrying about stringfying or parsing.

```
import pickle

def writeDBList():
    with open('DBListFile', 'wb') as fp:
       pickle.dump(DBList, fp)

def readDBList():
    with open ('DBListFile', 'rb') as fp:
       DBList= pickle.load(fp)
```

Comment: @vivek I added an answer for your followup question.

Comment: i guess the file 'DBListFile' will not be created if it does not already exist.

Comment: @vivek I'm afraid you're wrong. The `wb` flag while create the file if it doesn't exist.