# Fastest way to construct a derived UserList of class instances in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance

I have a class that inherits from UserList. When I instantiate this class, I pass an integer to it, and the list populates itself with the interger number of another class instantiations. For example:

```py
from collections import UserList

class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        x = 1

class bar(UserList):
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__(self)
        for i in range(num):
            self.append(foo())
```

This all works fine, however for large values of `num` it gets very costly. I have seen posts about this such as [Best and/or fastest way to create lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816600/best-and-or-fastest-way-to-create-lists-in-python) however I cannot get the list to do any of these options to itself.

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You may use a listcomp instead of calling `append()` a dozen times or use a generator.

Comment: The issue is how to set `bar = [list comp for i in blah blah]` just sets bar as a generic list and not my class I have created. I'm not sure how to d list comprehension inside the __init__() of bar like `self = UserList([block() for i in range(num)])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a temporary list comprehension and passing it to the super()**init**() of the UserList is many orders of magnitude faster for large `num`

```py
from collections import UserList

class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        x = 1

class bar(UserList):
    def __init__(self, num):
        temp = [foo() for _ in range(num)]
        super().__init__(temp)
```