# can't modify global 2-D matrix in python properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying a program in which I declared a 2D array named `grid` of size 5 x 5 globally in python.

```
grid = [[0] * 5] * 5

def main():
    global grid
    n,m = map(int,input().split())
    for i in range(n):
        li = list(map(int,input().split()))
        for j in range(m):
            if j < 5:
                grid[i][j] = li[j]
    print(grid)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Modifying the grid gives a weird answer. For example if the input is :-

```
2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

2 rows and 3 columns (`n` and `m`)

It gives the following output:-

```
[[4, 5, 6, 0, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0, 0]]
```

Even when I remove the line `global grid` from the `main` function, output remains the same. What is going on? I want it to update grid according to the input and leave the extra cells untouched i.e value `0`. If input is of size 2 x 3 then only the first 2 rows and 3 columns of the `grid` should be modified according to the input and rest of the elements should remain `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
[[0]*5 for _ in range(5)]
```

Instead of:

```
[[0] * 5] * 5
```

for more information, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).

Comment: Is there any way that's faster than this? I was using the method in question for 1D lists because it was faster than list comprehension and it always worked fine.

Comment: I think this is the fastest way... check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816600/best-and-or-fastest-way-to-create-lists-in-python)